# Syntax for Multiple Regression Model Using R

Tags: r

I am trying to perform multiple regression analysis on (y) variable with 5 (x) variables, using R studio. I am using the simple regression formula i.e.

```
lm(y~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5, data = qt)
```

Now what if I want to see interaction between (x1 and x3) and (x3 and x5), also if i want to square x5 as well, what will be the syntax for the regression model.
Is it going to be something like this:

```
lm(y~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x1x3 + x3x5 + x5x5, data  = qt)
```

or

```
lm(y~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x1*x3 + x3*x5 + x5*x5, data  = qt)
```

Please guide.

Comment: I believe it's the second one...I'd wonder why you don't just try it in R and see.  You'd know by the time someone answers.  Be an experimentalist.  It's faster and less passive.

Comment: See `?formula` for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See `?I()` which is appropriate for this situation. You need something like this,

```
lm(y ~ x1*x3 + x2 +  x4 + x3*x5 + I(x5^2), data  = qt )
```

`y ~ x1 * x3` is equivalent to  `y ~ x1 + x3 + x1:x3`, where `x1:x3` is the iteration between `x1` and `x3`  and the operator `I()` changes the class of an object to indicate that it should be treated ‘as is’ (see documentation).

Take a look to [this document](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Farnsworth-EconometricsInR.pdf) it is very useful. See page 17 in order get some hints about the use of `I()`

Comment: that is really helpful. Thankyou. I am actually very new to R and have never used it before.

Comment: You'll perpetually stay new to R if you don't just type things in and see what happens. All you ask is findable in the help to `formula` as recommended through the help to `lm`.